# How to mock a new object using mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to write unit tests using mockk.

I'm trying to figure out how to mock a new instance of an object.

For example, using PowerMockito we would write:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(Dog::class.java).withArguments("beagle").thenReturn(mockDog)
```

If the expected result of my test is mockDog, I want to be able to assert that it equals my actualResult:

```
assertEquals(mockDog, actualResult)
```

How would I accomplish this using mockk?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Using `mockkConstructor(Dog::class)` you can mock constructors in MockK. This will apply to all constructors for a given class, there is no way to distinguish between them.

The mocked class instance can be obtained by using `anyConstructed<Dog>()`. You can use that to add any stubbing and verification you need, such as:

```
every { anyConstructed<Dog>().bark() } just Runs
```

Comment: This is good information on how to handle test expectations, however it does not answer my question of how to perform asserts. If the class under test returns an instantiated object (actualResult), I'd like to be able to assert that it equals the mock object created (expectedResult).

Comment: When I add this gives me some error `io.mockk.MockKException: to use anyConstructed<T>() first build mockkConstructor<T>() and 'use' it`             
Can we add something like this as well to verify - `verify(exactly = 1) {  anyConstructed<PredictionCheckFunction>().check(any())}`

Comment: // a complete example to mockk a Date constructor will be.;
mockkConstructor(Date::class);
every { anyConstructed<Date>().time } returns Date().time;

Comment: It would be useful to add code which demonstrates the combined use of these two clauses.