# I am trying to use mockk anyConstructed but ending with Missing calls inside every { ... } block

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I am trying to return an object whenever a new object of a class is being created.

I have tried using anyConstructed with a spyk or even mockk object of PredictionCheckFunction

```
every { anyConstructed<PredictionCheckFunction>() } answers { predictionCheckFunction }
```

It results in the following error on the above line

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

In Mockito I would do something like this

```
whenNew(PredictionCheckFunction.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(predictionCheckFunction);
```

I want to make sure that every creation of PredictionCheckFunction results in an object of predictionCheckFunction

The example in this Question [How to mock a new object using mockk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742926/how-to-mock-a-new-object-using-mockk) allows me to only run a function on a mock object but not return one already created like above Mockito example `thenReturn(predictionCheckFunction);`  -

Example in referred SO Question -

```
mockkConstructor(Dog::class)
every { anyConstructed<Dog>().bark() }
```

Any help on how to do this while creation of a new object, is appreciated.

Comment: can you share the code to be tested?

Comment: What do you intend to verify in the test? if you want to verify a call is being made you can use verify { anyConstructed<PredictionCheckFunction>().method() } syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official tutorial, it seems we can't assign a mock instance to any constructed class instance, like:

```
mockkConstructor(TargetCls::class)
every { anyConstructed<TargetCls>() } returns mockk()
```

There's no example usage like the above codes. And that would case an exception...

However, you can write this, as the official tutorial states:

```
class MockCls {
  fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

mockkConstructor(MockCls::class)

every { anyConstructed<MockCls>().add(1, 2) } returns 4

assertEquals(4, MockCls().add(1, 2)) // note new object is created

verify { anyConstructed<MockCls>().add(1, 2) }
```

See the [tutorial](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).